# Amplitude at distance from source

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves

So, there is a sound at $S$, whose intensity $I$ obeys the inverse square law ($I \sim \frac{1}{x^2}$). At point $P$, at a distance $r$ from $S$, the air molecules oscillate with an amplitude of $8μm$. Point $Q$ is at a distance of $2r$ from $S$. What is the amplitude of the air molecules at $Q$? What is the relationship between amplitude and distance?

Comment: The amplitude $A$ is related to the intensity $I$ as follows: $I\sim A^2$

Comment: So, er,  $A^2 \sim \frac{1}{x^2}$ and therefore $A \sim \frac{1}{x}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Electro, the intensity $I$ - and energy density $T_{00}$ and similar quantities - is proportional to the squared amplitude,
$$ I \sim A^2 $$
Because the intensity must go as
$$ I \sim \frac{1}{r^2} $$
as the energy gets spread over the sphere of area $4\pi r^2$, it follows that
$$ A \sim \frac{1}{r}.$$ 
See e.g. the $1/r$ factor in this formula:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna#Elementary_doublet